# how to fill an array with 0's in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, binary, hex

For my project i need to make an hexadecimal calculator and additional to that i need to convert it to binary and show it, witch i know is easy. The max of hexadecimal i can read is '8' but if i read a hexadecimal with less than 8 characters i need to fulfill the first binary numbers with 0. Ej:

in Hex:ADA0CAFE

in Binary:10101101 10100000 11001010 11111110

but if i get an hex like:C45FA

the output should be: 00000000 00001100 01000101 11111010

Part of my code look something like this:

```
char hex[100];
printf("Hexadecimal: ");
scanf("%s",hex);
convert(hex);
```

and the function to convert it:

```
void convert(char hex[]){
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
    switch(hex[i]){
    case '0': printf("0000"); break;
    case '1': printf("0001"); break;
    case '2': printf("0010"); break;
    case '3': printf("0011"); break;
             .
             . 
             .
    }
```

So the part i dont figure out how to is to get the first position of the array fill with 0 and then start writing the array with the character of the hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `convert` find the length of the hex string passed, and put out leading `0000` strings to make up the length to 8. Perhaps like this:

```
void convert(char hex[]){
    size_t len, i;
    len = strlen(hex);
    for(i = len; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("0000");                     // pad with leading zeros
    }
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {              // the rest of the string
        switch(hex[i]) {
            case '0': printf("0000"); break;
            case '1': printf("0001"); break;
            case '2': printf("0010"); break;
            case '3': printf("0011"); break;
            .
            . 
            .
        }
    }
}
```